# UITableView: new row added to the top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Then, I would like the user to enter what he is thinking, like notes or reminds and these are displayed on a `UITableView`... and in my `TableView` I want the `TableViewCells` to be added at the top of the `TableView`. Currenty, the rows are added to the bottom of the `TableView`: I searched some questions already answered but any of the given answers are working...

Does anyone could help me to solve that?

Comment: By default a UITableView will add rows to the top. What happens if you add multiple cells?

Comment: Sorry, the question is not really complete: I fact, the user enter his text in a TextField and after the text is displaying on a uitextview in the cell, but, when I try to send text, [self.tableView reloadData] works fine and the cells are displaying by this event, I refresh datas with refreshcontroll and after the only problem is that the cells are appearing at the bottom of the TableView

Comment: It seems that your refreshcontroll should give some orders to ensure the new data at the top, you can order by time desc, or the id desc. This would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so hopefully I have got what you are after correctly:

- User posts notes and then these get inserted in rows at the top of the table?

So there are always three parts for both inserting and deleting rows. First you need to insert the row, then insert the information into your tableView data source and then refresh.

Use to insert the cell you want at the exact indexRow you want it, in this case you want it at the top so use indexPath row and section as 0.

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]; withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Next you need to insert it into your data. I usually use a mutable array so just insert the object at the correct index again:

```
[_tableViewData insertObject:text atIndex:0];
```

Then refresh the tableView:

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

This should be a pretty straight forward thing to achieve, making sure you get it in the right order and that your datasource stays correct is the trickiest thing as this will cause crashes.

Hope this helps